# Why does SHA2-224 use different IV's than SHA2-256?

Tags: hash, sha-256, initialization-vector, sha-2, sha-224

Given that it's otherwise just a truncation, I can *guess* that being able to compute the 224 value from the 256 value is an unwanted property, but that's just speculation.

Comment: Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/60966/51716

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The $\operatorname{SHA-224}$ is defined in the exact same manner as $\operatorname{SHA-256}$ with different initial values and the digest is obtained truncating the hash value, [FIPS PUB 180-4 Page 23](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=23).

The different **initial value** provides **domain separation**. With domain separation  $$\operatorname{SHA-224}(m) \neq \operatorname{SHA-256}(m)|_{224}$$ where $|_{224}$ is the truncation. If the IV's would be the same then the truncated values would be the same as the initial bits of the full hash, breaking domain separation.

A nice definition of domain separation can be found [Hashing to Elliptic Curves, ietf draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-irtf-cfrg-hash-to-curve-05#page-8)

> Cryptographic protocols that use random oracles are often analyzed
> under the assumption that random oracles answer only queries generated
> by that protocol.  In practice, this assumption does not hold if two
> protocols query the same random oracle.  Concretely, consider
> protocols $P1$ and $P2$ that query random oracle $R$: if $P1$ and $P2$
> both query $R$ on the same value $x$, the security analysis of one or
> both protocols may be invalidated.
>
> A common approach to addressing this issue is called domain
> separation, which allows a single random oracle to simulate multiple,
> independent oracles.  This is effected by ensuring that each simulated
> oracle sees queries that are distinct from those seen by all other
> simulated oracles.  For example, to simulate two oracles $R1$ and $R2$
> given a single oracle $R$, one might define
>
> $$R1(x) := R(\text{"R1"} \mathbin\| x)$$    $$R2(x) :=
>  R(\text{"R2"} \mathbin\| x)$$
>
> In this example, $\text{"R1"}$ and $\text{"R2"}$ are called domain
> separation tags; they ensure that queries to $R1$ and $R2$ cannot
> result in identical queries to $R$. Thus, it is safe to treat $R1$ and
> $R2$ as independent oracles.

A [random oracle](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/879/18298) is like a kind of hash function and the same concept applies to hash functions.

The initial values required to be a [nothing-up-my-sleeve numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number) to eliminate the suspicion of hidden properties, though [that is psychological](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16366/18298).

Similar to $\operatorname{SHA-224}$,

- $\operatorname{SHA-384}$ is a truncation of $\operatorname{SHA-512}$ with different initial values.
- $\operatorname{SHA-512/256}$ is a truncation of $\operatorname{SHA-512}$ with different initial values.
- $\operatorname{SHA-512/224}$ is a truncation of $\operatorname{SHA-512}$ with different initial values.

As a side note; the truncation, naturally, provides resistance to [length extension attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).